# how to loop through a hierarchical columns in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have a table that defines the hierarchy of our customer,  table1(id, country, state, region, …). And another table holds some data for each customer (id, data1, data2,…). I need to use stored procedures to generate a report in following format:

```
Detail report of each customer under country 01-state 01-region 01
Summary of country 01-state 01-region 01

Detail report of each customer under country 01-state 01-region 02
Summary of country 01-state 01-region 02
…
Detail report of each customer under country 01-state 01-region 0x
Summary of country 01-state 01-region 0x

Summary of country 01-state01

Detail report of each customer under country 01-state 03-region 01
Summary of country 01-state 01-region 01

Detail report of each customer under country 01-state 03-region 04
Summary of country 01-state 01-region 02
…
Detail report of each customer under country 01-state 03-region 0x
Summary of country 01-state 01-region 0x

Summary of country 01-state02
…

Summary of country 01
```

Currently I use cursor to loop through the hierarchy (country, state, region) and do some calculation to generate the report, the performance is not so great since we have millions of records. Following is the structure of my stored procedure.

```
declare @country_cursor cursor  
set @country_cursor =cursor local scroll for 
    select distinct country
    from table1
    order by country
open @country_cursor
fetch next from country_cursor into @country
while @@fetch_status=0
begin --country
    declare @state_cursor cursor 
    set @state_cursor =cursor local scroll for 
        select distinct state
        from table1
        where country=@country
        order by state
    open @state_cursor
    fetch next from @state_cursor into @state
    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin --state
        declare @region_cursor cursor 
        set @region_cursor =cursor local scroll for 
            select distinct region
            from table1
            where county=@country and state=@state
            order by region
        open @region_cursor
        fetch next from @region_cursor into @region
        while @@fetch_status=0
        begin --region
              print '--customers--'
            … (some calculation)

            print '--region summary--'
            ...(some calculation)
            fetch next from @region_cursor into @region
        end--region

        print '--state summary--'
        …
        deallocate @state_cursor
        fetch next from @state_cursor into @state
    end—state

    print '--country summary--'
      …
    deallocate @country_cursor
    fetch next from @country_cursor into @country
end--country
```

My questions is there any other way I could use to replace the cursor to improve the perfomance? I thought about the while loop, but I am not sure how to use while loop to loop through the hierarachy. And is the while loop is better than cursor?

Comment: You need a recursive [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (Example D on the link)

Comment: I don't think they are the same. My hierarchy is very straightforward, the one in the Example D is hidden in the table. I am not trying to get the hierarchy out from the table, I am trying to loop through the hierarchy to do some calculation and generate summary report for each hierarchy.

Comment: could you provide some sample data? what is the calculation you are trying to do? you can probably achieve this with a CTE to generate the hierarchy and a outer apply to run the "calculation".